# How to run a cron job every 5 hours (on Linux)

Tags: linux, cron

I would like to run a cronjob every 5 hours.

Now it's 11:54pm..

Checking the crontab guru, this `0 */5 * * *` seems to be correct, but the site also mentions something like this

> next at 2022-01-07 00:00:00

I would like to know why? Does it mean it runs the script no matter what at midnight(00:00:00) ? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Which site? ...

Comment: https://crontab.guru/#0_*/5_*_*_*

Comment: */5 means hours 0, 5, 10, 15, 20.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412483/how-do-cron-steps-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*/5` syntax means "every 5 units, starting from 0". So, if you use it in the hour position, it will match hours 0, 5, 10, 15, 20.

I'm assuming what you actually want is a strict 5 hour interval. So after hour 20, you want the next run to be at 20 + 5 hours, so at 1AM not midnight. If that's correct, there isn't an easy way to make cron work like that. It can do even intervals of all divisors of 24 though: every 2 hours, every 3 hours, every 4 hours, every 6 hours, every 12 hours.

To get the 5 hour interval, one possible workaround is to

- schedule the cron job to run every hour
- at the start of your script that the cron job runs, add extra logic to **check if it should run this hour**. For example, you could take the current time, and calculate the hours since epoch. And exit early unless the calculated number is divisible by 5.