# Ansible Playbook to create a cronjob and run every 2 hours

Tags: bash, ansible, cron

I need to write an Ansible Playbook that configures a linux machine to routinely prune files in `/etc/dummy/` older than 1 hour in a configurable `interval` as a configurable `user`

So, this is what I tried. But I am having some difficulties. So before actually running this in production, I need to verify if the `interval` is correct. i.e that the script will run every 2 hours. And I need to make sure the cronjob will be created and will be persisted even after a system reboot.

```
---
- hosts: servers
  vars:
    olderthan: 1
    intervals: 120 # needs to run every 2 hours, everyday
    user: tdp
    scriptpath: /etc/tmp/pruner.sh

  tasks:

    - name: Copy the file
      copy:
        src: "{{ scriptpath }}"
        dest: "{{ scriptpath }}"

   - name: "The Dummy Pruner"
     cron:
      name: "Prune the items at /etc/dummy"
      user: "{{ user }}"
      minute: "{{ intervals }}"
      hour: "*"
      day: "*"
      weekday: "*"
      month: "*"
      job: "sh {{ scriptpath }} >> {{ scriptpath }}/results.log 2>&1"
      state: present
```

and my `/etc/tmp/pruner.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /etc/dummy -name '*.*' -mmin +60 -delete > /dev/null
```

Can someone help me figure out the above issues?

Comment: _Can someone help me figure out the above issues_ > what issues? You described your purposed action but not what is problematic here.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: Issue is my doubts regarding the cron expression I have given. Need to run cronjob every 2 hours

Comment: So, you mean that you are going to trust the saying of a stranger on Internet above a trial from your side that is going to prove you with facts that it works? Just test it. You can test it on your controller first to be sure, or in a container, or in a VM spined by Vagrant, ...

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation [`cron` - Manage cron.d and crontab entries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html) the [Parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html#parameters) for [`minute`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html#parameter-minute) needs to be `0-59`. You may have a look into the there given [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html#examples).

Instead of describing the interval with 120 minutes for `minute` you need to describe it with every 2 hour `*/2` for `hour`.

**Further Q&A**

- [How to schedule cron jobs in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502490/)
- [How do cron steps work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412483/)
- [How do I set up a cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/)

... and many more

Answer (score 0):

Workaround can be putting complete line into the crontab by using module `lineinfile` or `blockinfile` if you need to put much more rather than one line.